# How to upgrade Gatsby starter blog deployed on Netlify via GitHub?

Tags: gatsby

Some weeks ago I deployed a blog based on the [Gatsby blog starter](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-blog) on Netlify.

I'm doing the *Git Repository Setup* via GitHub (https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/hosting-on-netlify#git-repository-setup).

How do I upgrade? How do I keep track of upstream changes?

Today I looked around with [diff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff). For my particular blog, it seems it's something I could do manually.

At the moment, it seems it would suffice to account for 2 things:

- The changes to *src/components/seo.js* of [74aed704ad706969945e7864a00d8adac1bd17e2](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-blog/commit/74aed704ad706969945e7864a00d8adac1bd17e2).
- The changes to *package.json*.

By *doing it manually*, I mean I would just edit *seo.js* and *package.json* replicating the changes at https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-blog.

Is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Usually you would "fork" the starter template and keep it in sync by merging the changes back into your forked repository. To get to this point you can follow these steps:

1. As a starting point fork the source repository [image: fork button on GitHub]
2. Add the original (so called "upstream") to git remotes. This depends on you git software you are using. On the console this would be

```
git remote add upstream git@github.com:gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-blog.git
```

3. Next step is to do all your changes (e.g. custom theme) on the forked repository. Later, when updates happening to the original repository you see information about it on GitHub:

[image]

4. Then you can update in your git by running the command below. This might require to resolve conflicts if you have changed core components - follow the steps git suggests for this.

```
git fetch --all; git merge upstream/master
```

5. Publishing the changes to Netlify with:

```
git push origin master
```

If you got your repository already created you will need to create a new one as you can't set the "forked by" information manually.

Answer (score 2):

There are sometimes good reasons for not using the Github Fork tool to fork your repo (lack of search is a big one for me). But you can still pull changes from upstream anyway.

Use good git hygiene and create a new branch to merge the upstream so you can test for breaking changes:

`git checkout -b upstarter`

Add the remote to upstream:

`git remote add upstream git@github.com:gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-blog.git`

Fetch the upstream:

`git fetch upstream`

Then when you merge it use the `--allow-unrelated-histories` argument:

`git merge upstream/master --allow-unrelated-histories`

You'll most likely have conflicts to resolve, but after that you can merge it back into master:

```
git checkout master
git merge upstarter
```